# Как запустить программу в другой папке? - C++

Tags: c++

Существует у меня функция, которая создает лог.
Как бы я не крутился - файл создается в папке, где запустили программу.
Я решил пойти другим путём, как при запуске .exe заставить работать программу в другой папке?
MVS компилирует мой проект в папку Debug, там и находится .exe, но логи появляются в папке с исходным кодом.

Вот на всякий случай функция создания лога:

```
void CreateLogFile()
{
    ifstream logg;
    logg.open("latest.txt");//Открываем старый файл лога - latest.txt
    if (bla.is_open())//Если файл существует
    {
        string date;
        logg >> date;//В первой строке записана дата.
        date = date + ".txt";
        logg.close();
        const char * newfilename = date.c_str();
        rename("latest.txt", newfilename);//Переименовываем файл в [date].txt
    }
    logg.close();
    string asdlog = "[" + getTime(1) + "." + getTime(0) + "_" + getTime(2) + "-" + getTime(3) + "-" + getTime(4) + "]";
    //getTime обрабатывает и возвращает время
    asdlog += '\r';
    asdlog += '\n';//По другому не работает перенос строки.
    ofstream lg;
    lg.open("latest.txt");
    lg << asdlog;//Записываем на первую строку дату.
    lg.close();
}
```

Выглядит это так: http://snap.ashampoo.com/JsChUMDW
Лог выглядит так: http://snap.ashampoo.com/VvT8IsWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему , то вам нужно сохранить log программы не в той папке , где находиться ваш .exe, а в какой - то другой вам просто нужно показать этот путь или относительно вашей папке , или относительно системы

```
logg.open("\log/latest.txt");
logg.open("C:\\mylog\\latest.txt");
```

При этом папка должна быть созданной.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream wr;//ofstream я выбрал для того , чтобы при отсутствии файла он создался
    /*wr.open("\log/latest.txt");*/ //или так
    wr.open("C:\\log\\new.txt" , ios::app);//используем для записи в файл флаг app(append) то есть дописываем в конец
    wr << "Some content\n";
    wr.close();
}
```

Comment: Пробовал по разному. Никак, ничего не работает.

Comment: А что за переменная bla.Вы точно создали папку с нужным названием и указали правильный путь.Я только что попробовал , у меня вышло.

Comment: Ну, у меня все переменные называются странно.   Не знаю, может MVS у меня шалит. Что за IDE у Вас? http://snap.ashampoo.com/fpssGv0l

Comment: Благодарю, /log/latest.txt никак не работает. А с созданной папкой на диске C работает без проблем

Comment: Я добавил код , надеюсь он вам поможет.Попробуйте вот так \log/latest.txt

Comment: Благодарю. А как создать папку, ищу сейчас в гугле, ничего толкового пока не нашел.

Comment: Вот так  https://ideone.com/SBdgpC